# mp3DirectCut error after windows 10 update: could not open wave/audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio, mp3, windows-10-upgrade

I have reinstalled the newest version (2.24), have lame encoder, stereo mix as default. have read all the related posts, but nothing helps

configuration: 
output device -> speakers
input device -> stereo mix
setting both to default (wave mapper) does not work either

decoder system (acm) or mpglib.dll (tried both)
encoder lame_enc.dll

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make it work again (Windows 10):

- Right click Windows button and select Settings
- Select Privacy
- Select Microphone
- Set "Allow apps to access your microphone" to "On"
  (You may set all the apps below to "Off" if you prefer)
- Now right click the sound speaker icon in low right corner
- Select Sound units
- Right click an empty space
- Select both "Show disabled devices" and "Show disconnected devices"
- Click on Recording Tab
- You should now see your Stereomix device
- If it is greyed out, then right click Stereomix and Enable it
- Now right click once again, and select Properties
- On the General Tab,
  make sure the Device Usage is set to "Use this device (enable)"
- Select the Listen Tab
- Make sure the "Listen to this device" is Cleared
  (otherwise you will hear sound as echoing loop)
- Select Enhancements Tab
- Set "Disable all sound effects" to Cleared

Done